# Getting the type of a column in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

My mate made the database for my Android app. For example, one of the tables is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id_fields_starring INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
    , fields_descriptor_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , starring_id INTEGER NOT NULL
    , form_mandatory INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
    , form_visible INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
    , FOREIGN KEY(fields_descriptor_id) REFERENCES pr_fields_descriptor(id_fields_descriptor) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , FOREIGN KEY(starring_id) REFERENCES starring(id_starring) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

From the fields of a table I need to know which of them is `INTEGER NOT NULL` and which is `INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`, because for the first case I must create dinamically an `EditText` and for the second case I must create a `CheckBox`. Any idea?

Comment: Uh .. `PRAGMA table_info(..)` is the preferred way to query table information in SQLite - unless one feels like SQL-Rambo and want to sift through the raw output of a `SELECT * sqlite_master`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Calling:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table1);
```

will dump the table information, e.g.

```
cid|name                 |type    |notnull |dflt_value |pk
0  |id_fields_starring   |INTEGER |0       |           |1
1  |fields_descriptor_id |INTEGER |1       |           |0
2  |starring_id          |INTEGER |1       |           |0
3  |form_mandatory       |INTEGER |1       |1          |0
4  |form_visible         |INTEGER |1       |1          |0
```

and simply find the row in the cursor with `notnull=1` and `dflt_value=1`

---

**Edit:**

To list all columns defined as `INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` this would work (`helper` is your instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper`):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(table1)", null);
try {
    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
    int typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type");
    int notNullIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("notnull");
    int dfltValueIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("dflt_value");
    ArrayList<String> integerDefault1NotNull = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String type = cursor.getString(typeIdx);
        if ("INTEGER".equals(type)) {
            // Integer column
            if (cursor.getInt(notNullIdx) == 1) {
                // NOT NULL
                String defaultValue = cursor.getString(dfltValueIdx);
                if ("1".equals(defaultValue)) {
                    integerDefault1NotNull.add(cursor.getString(nameIdx));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("integerDefault1NotNull now contains a list of all columns " +
            " defined as INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, " + integerDefault1NotNull);
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Jens, one more question. How I know for each column I have notnull=1 and dflt_value=1? I have a table with many columns, about 48.

Comment: @Jens This method works fine on emulator. Today I tested my app on device and I see that it is not detecting any column with not null and dflt_value=1, and I have about 18 columns like this. My device has 2.1. Could this be the problem?

Comment: The `table_info` pragma is pretty ancient (it's been in since 2001) - so it's not missing. Is your 2.1 device rooted?

Answer (score 2):

For those of you looking to do this programmatically in Xamarin perhaps (like me) you can execute the PRAGMA query against a SQLiteConnection as follows:

```
connection.Query<SqliteColumninfo>($"PRAGMA table_info({tableName})");
```

I couldn't find an object defined in the PCL Sqlite package for collecting the result so I created a class to collect the aforementioned components:

```
public class SqliteColumninfo
{
   public string Cid { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public int NotNull { get; set; }
   public int Dflt_Value { get; set; }
   public int PK { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query that I use to get table / column / data type / primary key info for all tables and views:

```
SELECT m.name AS table_name, UPPER(m.type) AS table_type,
  p.name AS column_name, p.type AS data_type,
  CASE p.pk WHEN 1 THEN 'PRIMARY KEY' END AS const
FROM sqlite_master AS m
  INNER JOIN pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p
WHERE m.name NOT IN ('sqlite_sequence')
ORDER BY m.name, p.cid
```

Answer (score -1):

This command returns a list of dictionaries which contain column name and datatype:

```
db.execute("SELECT name, type FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(?);", table1)
```

This command return columns datatype:

```
db.execute("SELECT  type FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(?);", table1)
```