# how to validate on dynamically created Edit texts

Tags: android

I am creating `EditText` dynamically in my android project according to record present in my  database table.

Each table has 3 columns with datatype text and integer.
Now I want to do validation for each `EditText` like if datatype is integer then it only accepts integer value or text then accepts string value.

how to do this.

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
{  
        //cout is a variable which returns no of columns in my table
        //add edittext to arralist

        enter_text=new EditText(DisplayTable_Grid.this);                
        String s="{datatype=text}";//  i stored data type in arraylist<hashmap<string>> so thats y its in such format
        String d=arraylist.get(i).toString();                                   

        if(d.matches(s))
        {        
            enter_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " not mached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        allEds.add(enter_text);                         
        allEds.get(i).setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(getColumnNames.get(i))));                              
        linearlayout.addView(enter_text);                       
}   //this is my code ..so now what can i do
```

Comment: Did you try using [InputFilter](http://www.almadevelop.com/2011/11/android-how-to-use-inputfilter-with.html)?

Comment: I have changed formatting of question, please look into it and please avoid spelling mistake

Comment: see TextView.setInputType()

Comment: see the updated code, how you are getting column and updating is quite complicated to understand

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `InputType` for each `EditText`.

For eg.

1) **Text Input:** `edtText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);`

2) **Number Input:** `edtText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

For more reference on

1) `InputType` and what all other input types, Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

2) For setting on [editText.setInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType(int)) method.

**UPDATE::**

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
{  
        //cout is a variable which returns no of columns in my table
        //add edittext to arralist

        EditText enter_text=new EditText(DisplayTable_Grid.this);                
        String s="{datatype=text}";//  i stored data type in arraylist<hashmap<string>> so thats y its in such format
        String d=arraylist.get(i).toString();                                   

        if(d.matches(s))
        {   
            //since this 
            enter_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(d.matches("{datatype=integer}"))
        {
            enter_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " not matched",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        enter_text.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(getColumnNames.get(i))));
        allEds.add(enter_text);
        //          allEds.get(i).setText();                              
        linearlayout.addView(enter_text);                       
}   //this might help you
```

Now user can only input the specific input type, which you provided for specific `EditText`

Comment: actully i want all dynamically.if my table has three column with data type text ,integer,integer.then i am getting size of that columns in one arraylist and according to that size will create  edit text using for loop.so in that case how do i give validation

Comment: what are those columns for? what do they have to do withe EditText?

Comment: @Bhakti `dynamic` or not, either in schema or code, you have to check what type of data you need to save, corresponding to which column, you can use following to get column type in java code http://stackoverflow.com/a/11754005/1225413 and base on your question, the answer is valid, since you only asked about validation

Comment: those columns are my sqlite table's fields and i want to set inputtype on edit text according to its datatype ...if data type of my columns are text,integer,integer respectively. then how to do that

Comment: @Bhakti just use TextView.setInputType(), did you try it?

Comment: yehh i already did that but i only want to setinputtype on edit text according to data type so how could i do that

Comment: @Bhakti You need to look at link => http://stackoverflow.com/a/11754005/1225413 , i provided to get column type, using `PRAGMA table_info(tableName);` you can get the column type and set the input type for each EditTExt

Comment: @Bhakti so what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `InputFilter`

```
//Allow only digits 
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
   public CharSequence filter(CharSequence text, int start, int end,
     Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
              if (!Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))) { 
                  return ""; 
              }
          }
    return null;
   } 
}; 

EditText edttext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
edttext .setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

This will allow only digits in your EditText.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
mEditText.setInputType(INPUT_TYPE)
```