# Cursor.getType() returns FIELD_TYPE_NULL if all the rows are null for a particular column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating a table using the following query:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE person_info ( uniqueId INTEGER,first_name TEXT,last_name TEXT,
address TEXT)";
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
```

I am inserting the values as follows:

```
  // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("first_name", "Anshul");
    values.put("last_name", "Jain");
    values.put("address", "Bangalore");

    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

**Note that I am not giving any value for uniqueId column. Thus, uniqueId column values are null.**

When I query the database and try to the type of each column using `cursor.getType(i)`, it returns [Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#FIELD_TYPE_NULL) for uniqueId column. According to the documentation, if all the column values are null, then it will return this value. But ideally it should return [Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER) because that's what I declared while creating the database.

Is there any other way of retrieving the correct column type when all the values of a column are null.

Comment: It does not [say](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType(int)) "all the column values" but "of the given column's value", i.e., it only looks at the current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. **In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container**.

[SQLite Docs](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

This behavior of returning `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL`(which according to you is not ideal) is absolutely ideal because SQLite is designed in that way only.

Querying the database to get the type of a Container using `cursor.getType(i)` will only work if the Container is not NULL otherwise it returns `Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL` (as in your case).

You can use `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)` for retrieving the datatype.

Check this SO answer -- [Getting the type of a column in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753871/getting-the-type-of-a-column-in-sqlite)

Comment: thanks for the useful insight ! Will need to use pragma table_info to determine the actual type. Thanks.